# Python: Grab all sections between <html> and </html> from a txt file

Tags: python, parsing

I use the following function to extract from a .txt file all the text found between `<html>` and `<\html>` sections using the following function:

```
def html_part(filepath):
"""
Generator returning only the HTML lines from an
SEC Edgar SGML multi-part file.
"""
start, stop = '<html>\n', '</html>\n'
filepath = os.path.expanduser(filepath)
with open(filepath) as f:
    # find start indicator, yield it
    for line in f:
        if line == start:
            yield line
            break
    # yield lines until stop indicator found, yield and stop
    for line in f:
        yield line
        if line == stop:
            raise StopIteration
```

The problem with this function is that it grabs only the first section found between `<html>` and `<\html>`. But there are other sections in the .txt file with `<html>` and `<\html>` tags. How can I adapt the above function to grab all the text found between all the `<html>` and `<\html>` tags? Sample .txt file can be found [here](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312513416534/0001193125-13-416534.txt).

When I execute the above function I do:

```
origpath = 'C:\\samplefile.txt'
htmlpath = origpath.replace('.txt', '.html')
with open(htmlpath, "w") as out:
     out.write(''.join(html_part(origpath)))
```

Comment: Instead of trying to parse through it manually, why don't you use `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: I have never used BeautifulSoup... OK I will check this out

Comment: You can also use `Scrapy` framework

Comment: Just a thought, but it might just simply be the 'raise StopIteration' that's causing the whole thing to stop. Try changing that to a break?

Comment: @TimB nope that doesn't work...

Comment: What is the purpose of your work? do you want to extract all `html` from whole txt file?

Comment: @Cyber I have installed BeautifulSoup but can I use it to open a saved .txt file on my computer and choose the sections that I need?

Comment: @NimaSoroush yes I want to extract all sections from the .txt that can be found between the tags <html> </html>. Not only the first sections that is between the first pair of <html> </html>...but all pairs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should Do the job and separate all the html parts in one .html file

```
writing = False
html_file = open('my_file.html', 'a')
with open(origpath) as f:    
    for line in f:
        # find start indicator
        if line == start:
            writing = True
        if writing:
            html_file.write(line + '\n')
        # yield lines until stop indicator found
        if line == stop:
            writing = False

html_file.close()
```

Comment: This is how you can put all in one `html` file

Comment: But I have the big html file in my computer and I can see the full result

Comment: ... I end up with an empty .html file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65180/discussion-between-nima-soroush-and-plug4).

Comment: It now works... I need to add this however: filepath = os.path.expanduser(filepath)

Answer (score -1):

You need to set it up in a way that can iterate over the same parameters multiple times. Also, is it necessary to set `start` and `stop` with `\n`? What happens if `<html>` moves directly into the following code without a newline? HTML code is structured the way it is so you can write everything in one line if need be.

So I would first start by changing your `start` and `stop` variables to not include `\n`.

```
start, stop = "<html>", "</html>"
```

Next, adjust your loop to iterate over the same info multiple times

```
with open(filepath) as f:
    # find start indicator, yield it
    switch = 0
    for line in f:
        if switch = 0:
            if start in line:
                yield line
                switch = 1
        elif switch = 1:
            yield line
            if stop in line:
                switch = 0
     raise StopIteration
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use regex for this:

```
import re

content = open("filepath.txt", "r").read()
htmlPart = re.findall("<html>.*?</html>", content)
htmlPart = [i[6:-7] for i in htmlPart]
```

Answer (score -1):

its simpler and better to use regular expression like this

```
import re
result = re.findall(r"(?si)<(html)[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>", filepath)
```